# Angular is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm learning angular and I have a very basic html with a js script and I keep getting 'angular is undefined' on line 1 of App.js. I have all of the angular scripts and my script in a Scripts folder. What am I missing?

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="appMain">
<head>
    <title>{{ Heading }}</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homePageViewModel">
    {{ Heading }}
    <button ng-click="SayHello()">Click me</button>

    <script src="Scripts/angular-min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
    var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', []);

appMainModule.controller("homePageViewModel", function($scope, $http,     $location){ 
    $scope.Heading = "This is the heading";

    $scope.SayHello = function () {
        alert('Hello');
    }
});
```

**Folder structure in VS:**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the console if angular is actually loaded?

Comment: Just to make sure, your angular*.js files are actually found inside a folder called Scripts, right?

Comment: @ochi yes..Checked, double checked.

Comment: Screenshot your apps file structure if seeing George's comment didn't answer you.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's the strangest thing...Could it have anything to do with the fact it's just an empty website folder in Visual Studio? I wouldn't that would have anything to do with it though.

Comment: We need to see your whole output structure, not just that folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your script is wrongly named it should be this

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular-min.js"></script>
```

Look at your file name and look at your script name.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. didn't even see that issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker actually your answer led to mine. When you said the cdn works, and he commented saying: every other file loads except that one, I knew it was from the file name or a problem with the tag. Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Given that I've [copied your code into a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGepMx); and the only changes I've made are to reference the CDNJS versions of Angular and Angular Route; and I'm not seeing an issue.

Your issue lies elsewhere.

Specifically, if you're building this project, your output folders need the same relative path to `Scripts`. In other words, your directory structure expects the following to be true:

```
 - index.html
 |
  - Scripts
  |
   - app.js
   - angular-min.js
   - angular-route.js
```

Another issue could be that you don't have `Copy to output Directory=true` or don't have the `angular-min.js` set as Content (something to be copied to the output folder).

Here's the codepen changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="appMain">
<head>
    <title>{{ Heading }}</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homePageViewModel">
    {{ Heading }}
    <button ng-click="SayHello()">Click me</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed my angular references to the CDNJS and it works! how come it's loading the App.js file from the Scripts folder but not the angular JS files?

Comment: @Anonymous We can't answer that question because we can't see the output of your build. You'd have to share screenshots in your question about the output of your build.

Comment: Just provided a screenshot

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your whole structure; not just that folder. Especially what it looks like after you build it (from Windows Explorer).

Comment: @Anonymous I bet I know the problem, if you right click on `angular-min.js` and look at its properties in Visual Studio, do you have `Copy to output directory` included? Is it also included as `content` as property?

Comment: Ahh,.. I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set type="text/javascript" in your angular script definitions.
try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is still not going to work because: check my answer.

Comment: true for HTML5 only, otherwise I saw it affect behaviour depending on the browser

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue about angular being undefined. In my code **type="text/javascript"** attribute was missing. After I added this attribute, it worked fine. Try this also if the solutions above do not work.